# Exchange/Powershell - Add data to new column rather than joining

Tags: powershell

I am trying to export list of users in mail enabled security groups to csv but want to have each member in a separate column rather than joining the existing column.

```
$Csvfile = "C:\SPOgroupmembers.csv"

$Groups = Get-DistributionGroup -Filter "Alias -like '*.spo'" -ResultSize Unlimited

$Groups | ForEach-Object {

    $GroupDN = $_.DistinguishedName
    $DisplayName = $_.DisplayName
    $PrimarySmtpAddress = $_.PrimarySmtpAddress
    $Members = Get-DistributionGroupMember $GroupDN -ResultSize Unlimited
   

    
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        DisplayName                        = $DisplayName
        PrimarySmtpAddress                 = $PrimarySmtpAddress
        Members                            = ($Members.Name -join ',')

    }


} | Sort-Object DisplayName | Export-CSV -Path $Csvfile -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8 #-Delimiter ";"
```

This is how it currently outputs:

| DisplayName | PrimarySmtpAddress | Member |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Test.SPO | Test.SPO@test.com | User1,User2,User3 |

This is what I am trying to achieve:

| DisplayName | PrimarySmtpAddress |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Test.SPO | Test.SPO@test.com | User1 | User2 |

I may be missing something simple but any help would be appreciated

Comment: This is doable however, not recommended, the output would not be easy to manipulate. In this case, it would make sense for each member to have their own row

Comment: You could probably use `Add-Member` to expand the custom object to the number of users, but @SantiagoSquarzon is correct, that probably is not advisable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to export the data where each member has it's own row, which in my opinion, would be the proper way to do it, you can have an inner loop to create a new `pscustomobject` per member of the Group:

```
Get-DistributionGroup -Filter "Alias -like '*.spo'" -ResultSize Unlimited | ForEach-Object {
    foreach($member in Get-DistributionGroupMember $_.DistinguishedName -ResultSize Unlimited) {
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            DisplayName        = $_.DisplayName
            PrimarySmtpAddress = $_.PrimarySmtpAddress
            Member             = $member
        }
    }
} | Sort-Object DisplayName | Export-CSV -Path ....
```

Comment: Makes sense, given that there's no fixed limit on the number of members, though I suggest naming the property `Member` (singular).

Comment: @mklement0 The big problem with OPs approach is if there is an unknown set of members the code would require a sort over `PSObject.Properties.Count` to the final obiect or `Export-Csv` would truncate data and also is not a good practice from a data analysis perspective

Comment: Agreed in general, but note that my approach creates a _fixed_ number of columns, so as long as that number of columns is _large enough to cover the max. count of  members across all groups_ - which may or may not be feasible in practice (and which could be calculated ahead of time) - `Export-Csv` will work as intended. For _data processing_ your solution is unquestionably preferable, but for the _human observer_ the one-row-per-group representation may be simpler to grasp.

Comment: Appreciate your assistance, I think I'll try the each member on a row rather than a new column for each.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to construct a `[pscustomobject]` *dynamically* is to construct an ordered [hashtable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Hash_Tables) first - which is easy to extend iteratively - and cast it to `[pscustomobject]` when done.

However, **in the context of creating CSV output, you need to commit to a fixed number of properties (columns)** ahead of time - *if feasible*<sup>[1]</sup>; e.g.:

```
$maxMembers = 10 # <- adjust this number to the max. count of members you expect

$Groups | ForEach-Object { ...

    # ...

    # Initialize an ordered hashtable with the static entries...
    $oht = [ordered] @{
        DisplayName                        = $DisplayName
        PrimarySmtpAddress                 = $PrimarySmtpAddress
    }
    # ... then iteratively add the Member1, Member2, ... entries
    foreach ($i in 1..$maxMembers) {
      $oht["Member$i"] = $Members[$i-1]
    }

    # Convert to a [pscustomobject] and output
    [pscustomobject] $oht

} | Sort-Object DisplayName | Export-CSV -Path $Csvfile -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8
```

**If *no* max. member count can / should be assumed**, consider denormalizing the data by using a single member column combined with creating a separate row for each member, as shown in [Santiago's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71610976/45375), which is unquestionably the better approach for subsequent *programmatic processing* of the data vs. the multi-column approach you're seeking, which may be simpler to grasp for the *human observer*.

---

<sup>[1] That is, you need to know how many members a group can have *at most*. You could even try to determine that count programmatically, ahead of time, but either way the resulting number may be too large to be practical.</sup>

Comment: Thanks, I think I'll give it a go anyway as would be interested to see the outcome. I should be able to put a max members count on the groups I am interested in.